# Android - Navigation Drawer Button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have integrated Navigation Drawer in my code. but it showing Back button instead 3 line drawer button. any one suggest me how can we add drawer button instead back button

[image]

Here is my code:

**MainActvity.java**

```
mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        // drawer_content_padding is set to 0 on handsets and to 240 on tablets,
        // so we can use it as a switch for locking the drawer
        //mIsDrawerLocked = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.drawer_content_padding) > 0;

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                mDrawerLayout,
                mIsDrawerLocked);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        BitmapDrawable background = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.top_bg);
        background.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("");
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment .java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private List<ProfileMenuItem> mDrawerItems;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    private boolean mIsDrawerLocked;
    private String mAvatarUrl = "nouser";
    private String mUserDisplayName = "nouser";

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(!mIsDrawerLocked) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, boolean locked) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerItems = new ArrayList<ProfileMenuItem>();

        // TODO: load data from server ------ DisplayName ----- Value -- Num - Type
        //mDrawerItems.add(new ProfileMenuItem( mUserDisplayName, mAvatarUrl, 0, 0));
        mDrawerItems.add(new ProfileMenuItem( "Title1", "tit1",2, 2));
        mDrawerItems.add(new ProfileMenuItem( "Title2", "tit2",2, 2));

        mDrawerListView = getListView();

        ProfileDrawerAdapter adapter = new ProfileDrawerAdapter(mDrawerListView.getContext());
        adapter.updateItems(mDrawerItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        getListView().setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        if(locked) {
            mIsDrawerLocked = true;
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, mFragmentContainerView);
        } else {
            // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
            // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        )
        {



            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && !mIsDrawerLocked) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        /*if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen() && !mIsDrawerLocked) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }*/
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle("");//R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }


    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
```

Comment: Try with:  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

The main part is here:

**NavigationDrawerFragment .java**

```
...
if(locked) {
    mIsDrawerLocked = true;                                           

    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN,   mFragmentContainerView);
} else {
            // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
            // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
```

I think `locked` value is`false` so by default `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` is called and show the back button instead logo image.

Hope its helps!